# java IBM portlet project - Where to put my css and jquery

Tags: java, jquery, portlet, websphere-portal

I have a simple Portlet that I have created with the following project structure.

[image]

At the moment all of the java script and the css is inline. I would like to add jquery and some css to this project. Can someone please tell me the correct folders to put a css and js folder in this project structure. It's tough to find examples on the net. I don't want to use themes etc I just want to try and keep it all within this project.

Also is there any problem with me adding jquery to the project? Should it just work?

thanks

**--attemped suggested solution--**

Hi,

So as per your suggestion I tried to add some javascript from jquery into my portlet .war module. However the link to the javascript does not seem to be correct. In my jsp I have..

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src='<%= 
        renderResponse.encodeURL(
            renderRequest.getContextPath() 
            + "/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js") %>'>
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src='<%= 
        renderResponse.encodeURL(
            renderRequest.getContextPath() 
            + "/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js") %>'>
```

When I view the source of the link after deployment I can see...

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src='/wps/PA_3m0jpe4o/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'>
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
```

And that link is incorrect.
        src='/wps/PA_3m0jpe4o/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'>

Here is the project structure with the js and css folder showing...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there should be no problem using *JQuery* in your own project, so then what third party libraries are intended to be used in.

I'm not quite familiar with *websphere-portal* thus not sure if it has some mechanism for resource injection, but I can tell you that the common location your static skin files and scripts should be in is under the **webapp** forlder of your project which should be **WebContent** as far as I know for Eclipse IDE. So the structure then can be:

> ```
> +- StockOnHandPortlet
> |  +- ... // Other project artifacts
> |  +- Webontent
> |  |  +- javascript
> |  |  |  \- your-js-file-1.js
> |  |  |  \- your-js-file-2.js
> |  |  |  \- ...
> |  |  +- css
> |  |  |  \- your-stylesheet-1.css
> |  |  |  \- your-stylesheet-2.css
> |  |  |  \- ...
> ```

Comment: Hi. I attempted your solution but it is not quite write. I have updates my original post to show my attempt. If you have any more advice that would be welcome. thanks

Comment: Could you please also post where files where added by updating the screenshot or just writing files structure?
I need also to know your web app context path? What is the package final name? What _wps_ and _PA_3m0jpe4o_ stands for in your projects structure?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for you. When you say my web apps context path I'm not sure what that would be equal to. I can always check if help me with some instructions. tks again

Comment: First and before moving forward, as I mentioned in my answer the static files should go under ***WebContent*** folder and not under *_StackOnHandPortler*.
So please update your configuration and feed me back with results :)

Comment: thank you for your help. After making that change it all worked!

Comment: You are always welcome, but please take good notes of all details next time (Something I have learnt because of hits I've in) :))

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<script type="script/javascript" src="${renderRequest.contextPath}/js/test.js"/>
```

I used this to import he JS file